# Can I get Thing stickers again after I use them?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I know that Thing stickers are incredibly powerful in battle, but I also know that sometimes you need a particular one to pass a certain area, or to beat a particular boss (or, at least, to make it a lot easier).

If I use a Thing sticker, is there a way of getting it back (such as redoing a level)? Or is there somewhere easier I can pick up ones I have already discovered and made into stickers?

I am just scared of running out of a Thing sticker when I really need it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can backtrack to the levels you found the Things in and pick them up again (except for the required ones like the Scissors and Fan).

You can also buy any Things you have previously found in the "shady" toad shop  in Decalburg (far west side of the area with the fling-a-thing sticker conversion place).

You can't purchase a previously acquired Thing if you have its sticker in your inventory or album.